# simple game using CSS, jQuery and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a game and still in the opening stages, I have the character and the code I thought would work, except when I run it nothing happens. I cant seem to find an error in it.

```js
document.body.onkeydown = function(event){

    var k = event.keyCode; 
    var chr = {
        updown: function (){
            var y = 0;
            if (k==38)  {
                --y;
            } else if (k == 40) {
                ++y;
            }
            return y; 
        },
        leftright: function (){
            var x = 0;
            if (k == 37) {
                --x;
            } else if (k == 39) {
                ++x;
            }
            return x; 
        }
    };

    rogue.style.top = (chr.updown()) + "px";
    rogue.style.left = (chr.leftright()) + "px";
}
```

```css
#rogue {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jumpOPP.css">
        <script src="jumpOPP.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="rogue" src="http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_143310_400x400.png" >
    </body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: You need to run some script on "document.ready" or equivalent to wire up your event. Right now your "move" event handler isn't attached to anything.

Comment: im pretty new to coding i dont suppose you could put that a bit simpler?

Comment: @TedNyberg there is no jQuery involved here, so that isn't the case.

Comment: Put the code in codepen/jsfiddle it will be easy

Comment: @TedNyberg Look at the body tag ;)

Comment: it moves but only slightly and only once, how do i make it keep moving in the diorection i want until i take my hand off the keys??

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function like this:

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(event){
    // Your event here
};
```

Take the handler off the body tag too.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/27f0rm7L/)

Comment: He's already got that.  Admittedly, I prefer your approach but he does have it.  Look at the body tag.

Comment: Yeah, and his never subscribes to the move event, mine does and works fine. His code to move the Rogue isn't great, but that's not that I'm looking at.

Comment: His code does hook to the event fine. Admittedly your is better practice, but his will work without issue. The event hook is not the problem.

Comment: I can see his body tag... Have you tested his code? Running it verbatim doesn't work, it never subscribes to that event handler, changing it as I suggested works perfectly. Granted the code he uses to move the rogue isn't up to much, but that isn't my fault.

Comment: it moves but only slightly and only once, how do i make it keep moving in the diorection i want until i take my hand off the keys??

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? The code I provided is working and listens to the move function. Your move function only moves the rogue 1 pixel in any direction so is hard to see. Are you sure you're not just missing it?

Comment: i noticed that, sorry

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention that. Rory has is pegged then, you're resetting the Y/X position to 0 every time before you moved it. You need to get the existing position an add/subtract 1 as appropriate as he shows.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you're using to set the `top` and `left` values is a little off. Note also that you need to parse the value to an integer so that you can add/remove from its value, and also provide a default.

Try this:

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(event){
    var rogue = document.getElementById('rogue');
    var currentY = parseInt(rogue.style.top || 0, 10);
    var currentX = parseInt(rogue.style.left || 0, 10);
    var speed = 3;

    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 38: // up;
            rogue.style.top = (currentY - speed) + 'px';
            break;
        case 40: // down;
            rogue.style.top = (currentY + speed) + 'px';
            break;
        case 37: // left;
            rogue.style.left = (currentX - speed) + 'px';
            break;
        case 39: // right;
            rogue.style.left = (currentX + speed) + 'px';
            break;
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzarotsv/1/)

Comment: and this would ensure the "rogue" keeps moving until i take my hand off the keys??

Comment: You need to buffer the keys pressed/released and inside your main loop check which is pressed and update your visuals accordingly. Because the 'onkeydown' event will fire only once until you release said key.

Comment: @ChristopherO'Brien yes, that's right. If you check the fiddle you'll see it working.

Comment: @PinkTurtle I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Create an array to hold your keys 'states'. True for down, false for up. Then inside your main game loop check which key is 'down' and update visuals accordingly i.e. move your toon or whatever ;) In a nutshell your keydown and keyup should *only* set states to said keys.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you're saying now. That is a better pattern, which I'll leave for the OP to implement :)

Comment: i swapped your code for mine, (i removed all of mine) and its not moving, was there a part of min i needed to retain??

Comment: Not really. So long as you have the above code in your JS file, and a reference to it in your body `keydown` event, it'll work fine.

Comment: im sure ill be back though

Answer (score 0):

Change your function as below (its just a sample)
Suggested reading: 
[Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)

...

```
updown: function (){
            var y = CURRENT_Y; // Get the current Y position of the image HERE
            if (k==38)  {
                --y;
            } else if (k == 40) {
                ++y;
            }
            return y; 
        },
        leftright: function (){
            var x = CURRENT_X; // Get the current X position of the image HERE
            if (k == 37) {
                --x;
            } else if (k == 39) {
                ++x;
            }
            return x; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly Working Answer: Run the Code Snippet and check

```js
//bind an event when the user presses any key
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (!e) {
        e = window.event;
    }
    //The event object will either be passed
    //to the function, or available through
    //window.event in some browsers.

    var code = e.keyCode;
    //that's the code of the key that was pressed.
    //http://goo.gl/PsUij might be helpful for these.

    //find our rouge image
    var rouge = document.getElementById("rouge");

    //get the image's current top and left position.
    //rouge.style.top will find the top position out of our
    //style attribute; parseInt will turn it from for example '10px'
    //to '10'.

    var top = parseInt (rouge.style.top, 10);
    var left = parseInt (rouge.style.left, 10);
    
    //We'll now compare the code that we found above with
    //the code of the keys that we want. You can use a chart
    //like the one in http://goo.gl/PsUij to find the right codes,
    //or just press buttons and console.log it yourself.

    if ( code == 37 ) { //LEFT

    //time to actually move the image around. We will just modify
    //its style.top and style.left accordingly. If the user has pressed the
    //left button, we want our player to move closer to the beginning of the page,
    //so we'll reduce the 'left' value (which of course is the distance from '0' left)
    //by 10. You could use a different amount to make the image move less or more.

    //we're also doing some very basic boundary check to prevent
    //the image from getting out of the page.

        if ( left > 0 ) {
            rouge.style.left = left - 10 + 'px';
        }
    } else if ( code == 38 ) { //UP
        //if we pressed the up button, move the image up.
        if ( top > 0 ) {
            rouge.style.top = top - 10 + 'px';
        }
    } else if ( code == 39 ) { //RIGHT
        //move the image right. This time we're moving further away
        //from the screen, so we need to 'increase' the 'left' value.
        //the boundary check is also a little different, because we're
        //trying to figure out if the rightmost end of the image 
        //will have gone
        //further from our window width if we move it 10 pixels.

        if ( left+rouge.width+10 < window.innerWidth ) {
            rouge.style.left = left + 10 + 'px';
        }
    } else if ( code == 40 ) { //DOWN
        if ( top+rouge.height+10 < window.innerHeight ) {
            rouge.style.top = top + 10 +'px';
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_143310_400x400.png" id="rouge" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px" />
```

Comment: No there is no div,check in your browser not in this code snippet @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @christopher-obrien Check This

Comment: Just copy the code in any html page in your computer ,

Comment: You're right, it works in a fiddle, but not in the snippet. You may want to provide a working example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Create an array to hold key states : `window.keyStates[];`

Update the `keyStates` var with `onkeyup` / `onkeydown` events.

```
document.body.onkeydown = function (event) {
    window.keyStates[event.keyCode] = true;
}
document.body.onkeyup = function (event) {
    window.keyStates[event.keyCode] = false;
}
```

Create a loop to loop game :

```
var mainLoop = function () {
    if (window.keyStates[38]) dostuff ();
    if (window.keyStates[40]) dootherstuff ();
    // etc....
}

window.setInterval(function() {mainLoop()}, 100);
```

The code is glitchy but you get the idea ? This way you can move your toon 2 directions at the same time too. Or manage virtually any key pressed at the same time.

Comment: I did a typo. If using this code don't use `else if`s in the `mainLoop` func, rather use plain `if`s. This way you can handle several keys pressed at the same time.